# Routes: can't get default scope(:locale) to work with user_path(id), always have to submit locale explicitly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, locale

I've done some research on this topic already, but I don't seem to be able to figure it out.

I have followed the [official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) to set up I18n, but I just don't get the default locale to be set properly (when no explicit locale is specified).

```
# routes.rb
require 'sidekiq/web'

Iq::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /de|en/ do
    # ...
  end
end

# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_language

  def set_language
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_options(options = {})
    options.merge!({ :locale => I18n.locale })
  end
end
```

In the OS X console:

```
$ rake routes | grep user
...
user GET      (/:locale)/users/:id(.:format)   users#show {:locale=>/de|en/}
...
```

In the Rails console:

```
$ Rails c
$ app.users_path
=> "/users"
app.users_path locale: :de
=> "/de/users"
$ app.user_path User.first, locale: :de
=> "/de/users/509fc01d77bb1e6a050000a0"
$ app.user_path User.first
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :locale=>#<User _id: 509fc01d77bb1e6a050000a0, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-11-11 15:11:25 UTC, updated_at: 2012-11-11 15:11:25 UTC, deleted_at: nil, group: "administrator", language: "de", active: true, sign_in_count: 0, name: "sysadmin", email: "support@sientia.ch", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$n/b7sTmUjEMoZI/jvq2jPuaNQqo1R1zbAIPpko9HT9PERagXclrPK", reset_password_token: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, confirmed_at: 2012-11-11 15:11:25 UTC, confirmation_sent_at: nil, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, save_vertical_menu_visibility_state: nil, contact_id: "509fc01d77bb1e6a0500008c", contact_name: "Sientia AG">}
from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `raise_routing_error'
```

Why doesn't this work? What did I forget?

Thanks a lot for help,
Josh

Comment: can't you pass it as default: `scope "(:locale)", locale: /de|en/, defaults: { locale: 'en' } do`

Comment: Nice, this does the trick...! Wanna create a real answer? Then I mark it as the correct one. Thank you!

Comment: But wait, what do I need the `default_url_options` method then? Doesn't it do exactly the same?

Comment: mmm... yup, seems weird `default_url_options` didn't play its role

Comment: what I suggested results in the locale always present in the url, which is maybe not what you expect. What if you do `app.user_path id: User.first.id`

Comment: @apneadiving: `app.user_path id: User.first => "/users/509fc01d77bb1e6a050000a0"`, that's interesting.

Comment: I deduce: it works, you're using mongodb, right?

Comment: Yes, it works, and I'm using Mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A co-worker A looked into it, and decided that I shouldn't put `(:locale)` into brackets. Another co-worker B mentioned, that he put it into brackets so that our tests work, where we do not want to specify the locale explicitly when calling an url helper method.

Co-worker A mentioned, that the application itself falls back to the `default_url_options` method mentioned above, when an url helper method is called without locale. This is great, because except the `root_path`, we always want an explicit language set.

In tests though, the `default_url_options` method is ignored (I'm not sure whether this is a bug or a feature, haha). So one has to do some workarounds:

```
# Fixes the missing default locale problem in request specs.
# See http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3448797
class ActionView::TestCase::TestController
  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :locale => I18n.default_locale }
  end
end

class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :locale => I18n.default_locale }
  end
end

# Fixes the missing default locale problem in controller specs
# See http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3448797#1041659
class ActionController::TestCase
  module Behavior
    def process_with_default_locale(action, parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil, http_method = 'GET')
      parameters = { :locale => I18n.default_locale }.merge( parameters || {} )
      process_without_default_locale(action, parameters, session, flash, http_method)
    end
    alias_method_chain :process, :default_locale
  end
end

module ActionDispatch::Assertions::RoutingAssertions
  def assert_recognizes_with_default_locale(expected_options, path, extras = {}, message=nil)
    expected_options = { :locale => I18n.default_locale.to_s }.merge(expected_options || {} )
    assert_recognizes_without_default_locale(expected_options, path, extras, message)
  end
  alias_method_chain :assert_recognizes, :default_locale
end
```

Put this into your spec_helper.rb file, and you're ready to go with your controller and request specs! :-)

Still, in the console, this doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
$ app.user_path User.first
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches...
```

Comment: I just stumbled across my own solution here, 1.5 years after I experienced it the first time! Isn't there a better solution yet?