# I18n routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, translation

I am implementing internalization in my app through I18n.

I have changed routing from:

```
    root 'sessions#new'
    get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
    post '/signup', to: 'users#create'
    get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
    post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
    delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
    resources :users, only: [:new, :show, :create, :index]
```

To:

```
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /pl|en/ do
    root 'sessions#new'
    get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
    post '/signup', to: 'users#create'
    get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
    post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
    delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
    resources :users, only: [:new, :show, :create, :index] 
  end
```

To change shown from www.example.com/users?locale=pl to www.example.com/pl/users

While testing

```
  test "should redirect show user when not logged in" do
    get user_path(@user)
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end
```

I have come across a problem.

> Error:

```
UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_show_user_when_not_logged_in:
> 
>     ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :locale=>#<User id: 753762654,
> first_name: "Jan", last_name: "Kowalski", password: "test12",
> student_id: "123456", created_at: "2016-12-16 21:02:17", updated_at:
> "2016-12-16 21:02:17", cookies_digest: nil, admin: true>} missing
> required keys: [:id]
>     test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:16:in `block<class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

How to solve that problem while keeping url like this: example.com/pl/users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the `locale` you want when calling `user_path` in test

like this `user_path(@user, locale: :pl)`

Comment: You can also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342734/routes-cant-get-default-scopelocale-to-work-with-user-pathid-always-have

Comment: There must be a better option to set the locale to the current one globally for all tests.